# interface<T> method<T2> where T2 : T

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Check out this snippet

```
public interface IExample<T>
{
    IExample<T> Exposes<TInclude>() 
        where T : TInclude;
}
```

I'm looking to compile time enforce that T is castable to TInclude.  Could do a runtime check, but would prefer it to be compile time.

The above complains that T isn't defined.

Any suggestions?  Is what I'm trying to do possible with C# generics?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: you got this backwards. I'm afraid your can't do what you are asking statically.

Comment: It is possible to have `TInclude : T`, but not `T : TInclude`.

Comment: what are you trying to do with your generic interface? What is the Expose<Tinclude> supposed to return and where is TInclude should be used? I think `IExample<TInclude> Exposes<TInclude>();` should work instead.

Comment: @DanielA.White yeah thats what i figured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rephrasing your question:

> It is possible to make a `where` clause that enforces the constraint that `TInclude` is `T` or any type derived from `T`. I'm looking to enforce the "opposite direction" constraint: that `TInclude` is `T` or any "base type" of `T`. Is this possible?

No. C# doesn't support that kind of constraint. Sorry.

> Any suggestions?

Scala supports that kind of constraint I think. As does Java, though the way Java does it is a bit odd. But I suppose you don't want to change languages.

Can you describe in more detail the concept you actually want to represent with this interface? If we know what you're trying to do then it will be easier to give you pragmatic advice.

Comment: i'm going to go with a runtime check, i think.  compile time safety is nice but isnt that important i guess.  basically, the system we're building is specifically "exposing" certain classes as interfaces they implement.  kinda a lot to explain.  so TContract is an interface that may be implemented by T and i want to catch any mistakes at compile time.

Comment: @JoshuaEvensen: I wonder if .Net code contracts could turn these runtime checks into compile time checks.

Comment: @Brian you know, that sounds right.  I haven't used code contracts yet.  Gonna look into it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the type constraint to the interface level, like that:

```
public interface IExample<T, U>
    where T : U
{
    IExample<T, U> Exposes();
}
```

Comment: To expand on Marcin's solution, generic type constraints must be on the thing which declares the generic -- in this case the interface, not the method.

Answer (score 0):

It could be implemented someday: see [1.2 Generalized Constraints](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/64042/ecoop06.pdf)

Comment: That link isn't working, which is why link-only answers are frowned upon.

Comment: It seems to be back. I got a message saying "site down".